# How do I combine 2 combined tables and then add a column that compares them?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a report that compares two sets of data. One is a Training table listing who we have trained. The other is a project table listing who has participated in a project.

I want to group the Trained and participants by department so we know which departments aren't participating after training.

I wrote the following two statements to show me the counted number of trainees and particpants by department:

Shows the participants counted by department:

```
SELECT emp.DEPT_MANUAL, COUNT(pt.SSO) AS PARTIC
FROM PROJECTTEAM pt, EMPLOYEES emp
WHERE emp.SSO = pt.sso GROUP BY emp.DEPT_MANUAL
ORDER BY emp.DEPT_MANUAL DESC
```

Shows the trainees counted by department:

```
SELECT emp.DEPT_MANUAL, COUNT(train.SSO) AS TRAINED
FROM TRAININGROSTER train, EMPLOYEES emp
WHERE emp.SSO = train.sso GROUP BY emp.DEPT_MANUAL
ORDER BY emp.DEPT_MANUAL DESC
```

Some info about these two tables.

Both the PROJECTTEAM & TRAININGROSTER are linked to the EMPLOYEES table via SSO. The EMPLOYEES table has a field DEPT_MANUAL.
Not every SSO in TRAININGROSTER is in PROJECTTEAM (Going forward they will be)
Not EVERY SSO in PROJECTTEAM has an associated DEPT_MANUAL in the EMPLOYEES table.

I want to combine these two select statements and then add another column which divides the counts to give me a %. It should look like this:
[image]

How do I combine the listed selects and then add the 4th column shows that divides the trained by the participants?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care about the event Id?

Comment: No, I just added those in to show that 1 person can be in either table multiple times. But I really only care about them being represented once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way.  How you do it is limited by the database you are using, but here's how it might look in **Oracle**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.DEPT_MANUAL, a.PARTIC_COUNT, a.TRAIN_COUNT, a.TRAIN_COUNT/a.PARTIC_COUNT AS PCT
FROM (
SELECT emp.DEPT_MANUAL, 
  (SELECT COUNT(pt.SSO),
  FROM PROJECTTEAM pt, EMPLOYEES emp_partic
  WHERE emp_partic.SSO = pt.sso
  AND emp_partic.DEPT_MANUAL = emp.DEPT_MANUAL) as partic_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(train.SSO)
  FROM TRAININGROSTER train, EMPLOYEES emp_train
  WHERE emp_train.SSO = train.sso
  AND emp_train.DEPT_MANUAL = emp.DEPT_MANUAL) as train_count
FROM EMPLOYEES emp
) a
```

Where in another database such as **SQL Anywhere**, it might not require the pseudo-table (the "a" in the oracle version) and look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.DEPT_MANUAL, 
  (SELECT COUNT(pt.SSO),
  FROM PROJECTTEAM pt, EMPLOYEES emp_partic
  WHERE emp_partic.SSO = pt.sso
  AND emp_partic.DEPT_MANUAL = emp.DEPT_MANUAL) as partic_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(train.SSO)
  FROM TRAININGROSTER train, EMPLOYEES emp_train
  WHERE emp_train.SSO = train.sso
  AND emp_train.DEPT_MANAUL = emp.DEPT_MANUAL) as train_count,
  train_count/partic_count AS PCT
FROM EMPLOYEES emp
```

Comment: This worked! I made some adjustments like dividing participated by trained but the code works exactly how I need to. Thank Jim

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I added DISTINCT in there to keep the count for a department from repeating once per employee in that department.